# How to "Export" subnets and VPCId from a parent template in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm working with AWS CloudFormation. I have 3 templates: one for EKS (Kubernetes cluster) "parent template" and two child templates for group nodes. I'm creating VPC, subnets, security groups in the parent template and I need to use them in each child template.

I can't use nested stacks because I don't want a new instance of EKS. If I use `Output.export.name` I get:

> The Name field of Export must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs.

This is a simplified version of the parent (EKS) template:

```
Resources:
  InternetGateway:
    Type: "AWS::EC2::InternetGateway"
  KubeRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: Kubernetes-Role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
              "Service": "eks.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
          }
        ]
      }
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSServicePolicy

  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock:  !Ref VpcBlock
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true

  Subnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet01Block
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  Subnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2b
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet02Block
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  Subnet03:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2c
      CidrBlock: !Ref Subnet03Block
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  Route:
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway

  Subnet01RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet01
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

  Subnet02RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet02
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

  Subnet03RouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      SubnetId: !Ref Subnet03
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable

  ControlPlaneSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Cluster communication with worker nodes
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  KubeCluster:
    Type: AWS::EKS::Cluster
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref ClusterName
      ResourcesVpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - !GetAtt ControlPlaneSecurityGroup.GroupId
        SubnetIds: 
          - !Ref Subnet01
          - !Ref Subnet02
          - !Ref Subnet03
      RoleArn: !GetAtt KubeRole.Arn

Outputs:
  KubeName:
    Description: Kubernetes Cluster name just created
    Value: KubeName
    Export:
      Name: !Ref KubeCluster

  SubnetIds1:
    Description: Subnet01 in the VPC
    Value: SubnetIds1
    Export:
      Name: !Ref Subnet01

  SubnetIds2:
    Description: Subnet02 in the VPC
    Value: SubnetIds2
    Export:
      Name: !Ref Subnet02

  SubnetIds3:
    Description: Subnet03 in the VPC
    Value: SubnetIds3
    Export:
      Name: !Ref Subnet03

  SecurityGroups:
    Description: Security group for the cluster control plane communication with worker nodes
    Value: SecurityGroups
    Export:
      Name: !Ref ControlPlaneSecurityGroup

  VpcId:
    Description: The VPC Id
    Value: VpcId
    Export:
      Name: !Ref VPC
```

Is there a workaround this problem? I wouldn't want to "output" the value and then rely on a person to copy them and then paste them as parameters of the child template. We have a lot of subnet, VPC and security groups, so the chances of selecting the wrong values are very high.

Comment: [Exporting Stack Output Values](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html) is definitely the way to go. Can you edit your question to show us the problem you were having with using `Export`?

Comment: Hey @JohnRotenstein thanks for replying! this is the template where I'm using Output Export and having problems. All my exports depend on Resources and all of them prompt this message 


`The Name field of Export must not depend on any resources, imported values, or Fn::GetAZs.`

maybe I need to modify my template to workaround this problem but I don't see how

Comment: The error message is quite explanatory. The `Name` of the output must always be a fixed string. It should not vary based upon the content of the template. For example, the output of the VPC should have a name of `VPC`, so that other templates can import it via this known name. Only the the `Value` should change based upon what is being built. You could probably swap your `Name` and `Value` fields and things will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CloudFormation ["Outputs section structure"](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) documentation it says:

> For outputs, the value of the Name property of an Export can't use Ref or GetAtt functions that depend on a resource.

What you can do is:

> You can use intrinsic functions to customize the `Name` value of an export.

Like it shows in the examples:

```
Export:
  Name: !Join [ ":", [ !Ref "AWS::StackName", AccountVPC ] ]
```

Now, in your `template` I think you are passing a name into the `Value` key of your `Outputs`, and a reference to a resource in the `Export.Name` property. Inverting this two should fix your current problem.

I hope it helps.